# How to draw a title bar in a client area using win32 API?

Tags: c++, win32gui

I want to draw the whole window myself, so I used WS_POPUP to remove non client area when I was creating the window.  But how can I make a portion of window function like a standard title bar (with moving and window closing functionalities)?  Could someone give me an example how to do it?

**Template:**
[image]

Comment: Have your window handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message and return the appropriate code (HTCAPTION, HTCLOSE, etc) for the various areas you are interested in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi, I tried handling NCHITTEST message, but I couldn’t get it working, Could you write an example?